# How to get the no.of Items from a Pivot Field in Report Filter using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I used the below line to get the no.of items from a Pivot Field in a "Report Filter": `MsgBox pt.PageFields(5).PivotItems.Count`

But it is returning 0 everytime. I'm not sure if this is the correct way. This field for sure has Pivot Items in it. Can someone help me?

Comment: Pramod: You've 'edited' your question so much that now this is a completely different question, and as a result doesn't match the answers given below. Suggest you revert your edits, and post a new question.

Comment: Hi @jeffreyweir Thanks for the suggestion. I've posted a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38753567/how-to-access-pivot-items-of-a-pivot-field-which-is-present-in-report-filter-usi I know I didn't make any sense after editing the question. I appreciate your comment instead of downvoting my question

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to know the count of *visible* items and not just of *all* items, then iterating through each item to test the .visible status is by far the simplest method. But it might take a while: A per a post I wrote some time back at http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2013/11/14/filtering-pivots-based-on-external-ranges/ it takes upwards of one minute and twenty seconds just to read the .visible status of a PivotField with 20,000 items in it. Many of the PivotTables I work with easily have that number of items in them, so when I write code that must work on *any* PivotField I don't use that approach.

So if your PivotField has many items, a less straightforward - but potentially much faster - way than Doug's fine approach above is to make a copy of the PivotTable, remove/unfilter every field but the one of interest, change the layout of that field to a PageField, and then count how many rows it occupies.

I usually make TWO copies of the PivotTable, and use one of them to determine what is currently visible in the field, and the other to determine

- What (if anything) is filtered but NOT visible due to filters applied
  on other PivotFields; and
- What (if anything) is not filtered AND not visible

The code to accomplish this is pretty complicated, and part of a commercial add-in I'm building, so I can't share it I'm afraid.

Comment: Hi @Jeffreyweir I'm trying to count the no.of items not the no.of visible items. Please refer to my edited question

Comment: Note that your edited question is a very different question to the one you initially asked, and I'm still not 100% clear on what you want, because your comment above says you want the count, but your edited question says you want to print each PivotItem along with its visible status. Please clarify.

Comment: Sorry about that. Actually to do either of them I need to access the pivot items. My main problem is accessing the pivot items. So, I tried printing the no.of pivot items in my previous to edited question. The actual thing I want to do is to get the list of visible items inside an array, one after other. To do so, I'm trying various ways to access the pivot items of a pivot field present in a Report Filter. Thanks for asking