# How to access Pivot Items of a Pivot Field which is present in Report Filter using VBA

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

I used the below code to print the Pivot Items present in Each PivotField and their visible status. I have 5 Pivot Fields in the Report Filter.

The problem is, it is fetching the no.of Pivot Fields Properly. But when it comes to the no.of Pivot Items is returning 0 for every pivot field. In real each Field has many items. I'm not trying to print the visible items. But Items and their Visible Status.

```
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pi As PivotItem

Set pt = Sheets("Reasons").PivotTables("PivotFields")
For Each pf In pt.PageFields
     For Each pi In pf.PivotItems
         Debug.Print pi.Name & " : " & pi.Visible
     Next
Next
```

Comment: Pramod: can you elaborate a little more on the outcome you're after? In your other post you say that you want an array of visible items. Is this also the case here? Out of interest, what do you intend to do with the array? I have some ideas but it would help if I knew your ultimate intent

Comment: Thanks for you interest Jeff. I have 5 Pivot Fields on my Report Filter and user can select items from any of them. Whenever they make a selection on one Filter, I want to collect the visible items into an array and pass that array to VisibleItemsList method to reflect the same changes in other pivot table. In simple words, I want to apply filter on one pivot table to other pivot table whenever a pivot field's items are selected

Comment: And I take it you're using excel 2007?

Comment: Can you also advise how many items roughly in each of the 5 pivotfields? Easiest way to tell is to create a pivot with just one field in it as rowfield and see how many rows it takes up

Comment: 3 of them have maximum of 6 Items. But 2 of those have 30 and 53 Items each. So Row Label is not an option for me as it'll occupy too many rows and I have few other things to show below the filters. To over come this, I've named the cell where each field is present and whenever a change occurs in that cell, I move that field to Column Label get the changes and reflect them on other pivot table.

Comment: But the method is tried doesn't work effectively. Because, when a field is moved from Report Filter to Column Label, the Field below that is occupying the previous fields place triggering a change in the cell which in turn causes another macro to run. This is becoming a chain event. So, rather than moving the fields i want to get the Visible Items when the Field is in Report Filter itself. Hope I explained my situation clearly.

Comment: And, I'm using Excel 2007

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my code at the below link that lets you sync PivotTables efficiently in the event that you can't use Slicers
http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2012/08/28/update-specific-pivot-tables-automatically/

Comment: Awesome Jeff. Simply Superb. I was struggling to do this for past 1 week and you solve it in a blink of an eye. I've downloaded the sample workbook and modified according to my need and it's working perfectly.

Comment: Cool. Glad to have helped

Comment: I have a doubt Jeff. I see that when I applied filter on ONE field, all the other fields status is also getting copied. Is it possible to apply filter ONLY ON THE FIELD I changed?

Comment: Not easily.  Read these. 
http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2014/07/07/what-caused-that-pivottableupdate-part-one/ 

http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2014/07/08/what-caused-that-pivottableupdate-part-two/  
http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2014/07/09/what-caused-that-pivottableupdate-part-tres/
http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2014/07/10/what-caused-that-pivottableupdate-episode-iv/